# Any tool/software in windows for viewing ELF file format?

Tags: windows, assembly, linker, reverse-engineering, elf

There are lots of PE file browsers. Here is a list of good ones if you are interested:

> PE File format viewers:
>
> - PE Explorer http://www.pe-explorer.com/
> - PE VIew:  http://www.magma.ca/~wjr/
> - PEBrowse Professional http://www.smidgeonsoft.prohosting.com/pebrowse-pro-file-viewer.html
> - PE Browse Professional Interactive - http://www.smidgeonsoft.prohosting.com/pebrowse-pro-interactive-debugger.html

I'm still working on windows & I want to view the ELF files. Are there any tools? I'm googling but couldn't find any till now.

Answer (score 17):

`readelf` and `objdump` are both excellent utilities if you are on a Unix box.
Both are provided by Cygwin.

`readelf` will give you a good overview of the ELF header information, section headers.  You can also use it to get relocation and symbol information. Overall, `readelf` can give greater detail on the contents of an ELF file.

`objdump` has some similar features to `readelf`, but also includes the ability to disassemble sections.

Answer (score 3):

I like objdump. I think it comes with the Mingw and/or cygwin distributions.

Comment: Amen to that. Oh, and IDA Pro ain't half-bad either for looking at elf files ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's *quite* what you're looking for, but it may still be useful - Agner Fog has an object file converter available here:

http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv

Answer (score 2):

The project biew has been renamed into beye:

http://beye.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [HT editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hte/).Though it is lack of a beautiful GUI,it do support a lot of file formats which of course include elf.

Answer (score 1):

I've used BIEW before

http://biew.sourceforge.net/

Apparently it can process ELF headers

> Support for a-out, arch, coff-386, ELF, MZ, jvmclass, LMF, LE and LX, NE, NLM-386, PharLap, PE, RDOFF, SIS and SISX executable formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [ELFSharp](http://antmicro.com/OpenSource/ELFsharp) project. It's a C# library, not a complete tool, but it's very easy to use and, what is very important, active (look at its [github](https://github.com/konrad-kruczynski/elfsharp)).