# what happens to a static c function that is not called

Tags: c, compilation, linker

if you have something like this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    int i;
#if (num>99)
    i = func();
#else
    i= func2();
#endif
    return 0;
}

static int func()
{
    return 1;
}
static int func2()
{
    return 2;
}
```

Is it reasonable to expect that depending on if `num` is bigger or smaller then 99 ether `func` or `func2` will be removed from the runtime code?

Or would I rather need to also embed the functions in an `#if` to achieve this goal?

Comment: "The runtime code" isn't part of the C standard, so the C standard cannot answer this question. It is a matter of how your linker operates. Dead code removal is certainly a known and used optimization strategy that is available on many platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on linker,what does it with dead code is linker specific.
You should also include function definition under `#if` to make sure that it wont results into machine code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on optimization level. On linux you can check it youself using
`readelf -s ./a.out | grep func2`

But I think you use windows, so you need some similar tool http://www.pe-explorer.com/ for example.

Here is list of tools: [Any tool/software in windows for viewing ELF file format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221806/any-tool-software-in-windows-for-viewing-elf-file-format)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to embed the function definitions also in an #if to achieve the goal.

code may be something like this:

Let's say the variable "num" is getting populated form configuration.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    int i;
#if (num>99)
    i = func();
#else
    i= func2();
#endif
    return 0;
}

#if(num>99)
static int func()
{
    return 1;
}
#else
static int func2()
{
    return 2;
}
#endif
```

Hope it helps. Thank you!