# Are libraries for testing incorporated in final build

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, go-modules

I'm wondering if the libraries that I use for tests only will be included in the final build distribution. I see dependencies in `go.mod`/`go.sum` files but I can't check final binary.

I guess that the Go build tool deals somehow with redundant code but I didn't find any pieces of evidence.

Could somebody point me to that spot in the documentation or describe behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Official doc: [Command go: Compile packages and dependencies:](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies)

> When compiling packages, build ignores files that end in '_test.go'.

Also from package doc of [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/):

> To write a new test suite, create a file whose name ends _test.go that contains the TestXxx functions as described here. Put the file in the same package as the one being tested. The file will be excluded from regular package builds but will be included when the “go test” command is run.

Building your app doesn't even touch the test files. So no, dependencies only referred to from tests are not included in the executable binary.

Also how hard is it to test? Write a simple app, build it. Note the size of the compiled binary.

Add a test file, refer to some lib. Build again, the size won't change. Now if you refer to the package from the app and build again, it will grow.

Example:

```
package main

func main() {
    println("Hello world")
}
```

Built on linux (Go 1.13), size is: **1,148,861 bytes**.

Adding a test:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestOne(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println(time.Now())
}
```

Size doesn't change. Now adding this `TestOne()` function (along with the required imports) to the main app: size increased to **2,165,259 bytes**.

Comment: An even easier test would be to import a non-existant library in your test, then watch the standard build succeed.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering if the libraries that I use for tests only will be
>   included in the final build distribution. I see dependencies in
>   go.mod/go.sum files but I can't check final binary.

When the binary is built, it contains a tons of additional information, including a table of symbols. Where a symbol is an identifiable name in your code.

read more about this https://www.grant.pizza/dissecting-go-binaries/

Using that you can list imported packages using programs like `readelf`, `objdump` or `nm` for linux like systems, for a windows system, the executable file format is named [PE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221806/any-tool-software-in-windows-for-viewing-elf-file-format) and you will need specific interpreters.

see those two sessions

```sh
[mh-cbon@Host-001 pyt] $ cat main.go 
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world!")
}
[mh-cbon@Host-001 pyt] $ go build -o bin
[mh-cbon@Host-001 pyt] $ nm bin | grep testing
```

A program built with the `testing` package

```
[mh-cbon@Host-001 pyt] $ cat main.go 
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world!")
    _ = testing.T{}
}
[mh-cbon@Host-001 pyt] $ go build -o bin
[mh-cbon@Host-001 pyt] $ nm bin | grep testing
00000000004e30e0 R go.itab.*testing.benchTimeFlag,flag.Value
0000000000574b90 B testing.benchmarkMemory
00000000005614b0 D testing.benchTime
0000000000494320 T testing.(*benchTimeFlag).Set
```